# Is every normed space Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I would like to know if normed spaces $(X,||\cdot||)$ have the Hausdorff property.

This would be useful to reuse results proved in the context of general topology into functional analysis theory. For instance, this would give automatically that points are closed sets and by continuity we would have that circumferences $S_r = \{x \in X:||x|| = r\}$ are closed sets.

So how does one proof that normed spaces are Hausdorff?

Comment: The answer is yes, and this is fairly obvious if you know what "Hausdorff" means and what a "normed space" is.  Where, then, are you running into trouble?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Use balls of radius smaller than half the distance between the points.

Indeed, every metric space is in fact [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space#Examples_of_normal_spaces) and Hausdorff.